# Copy SQL Azure Hyperscale

Tags: azure-sql-database

I wanted to try SQL Azure Hyperscale, after I selected it seems I no longer have the option to move out of it. If I try, I get this message "databases cannot be moved out of hyperscale tier".

The Copy option is not available and restore does not give you the capability of choosing a different configuration.

Is there a way to move to another Tier ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Once a database is migrated to Hyperscale, it cannot be migrated
> directly to a non-Hyperscale service tier. At present, the only way to
> migrate a database from Hyperscale to non-Hyperscale is to
> export/import using a BACPAC file or other data movement technologies
> (Bulk Copy, Azure Data Factory, Azure Databricks, SSIS, etc.)

Source is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-service-tier-hyperscale?wt.mc_id=MVP#known-limitations).

Database copy for Hyperscale is now in Public preview as announced [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-database/database-copy-preview-on-azure-sql-database-hyperscale/ba-p/1623866?wt.mc_id=MVP) on Sep 22, 2020.

Comment: Copy database is now in Public Preview. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-database/database-copy-preview-on-azure-sql-database-hyperscale/ba-p/1623866?wt.mc_id=MVP

Comment: From my experience, copy only creates a new hyperscale DB, you still don't have the option to change tiers.